# gitlab runner - how to cache images rather than build every time?

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have setup gitlab runner to make use of the `docker/compose:latest` image to run a set of services.

By setting     `pull_policy="if-not-present"` in the `config.toml` the `docker/compose:latest` image is cached and not pulled each time.

How can I set the docker service used in the test stage to use cached images (i.e. those being started using `docker-compose up -d` )? I'm a bit confused by the `dind` service.

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  CI_REGISTRY: my-docker-registry.local:5000

image:
  name: docker/compose:latest

services:
  - name: docker:dind
    command: ["--insecure-registry=my-docker-registry.local:5000"]

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker-compose up -d
```

`/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` as follows:

```
                                                   concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "user1"
  url = "http://gitlab.example.local/"
  token = "<MYTOKEN>"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    extra_hosts = ["my-docker-registry.local:192.168.1.100"]
    tls_verify = false
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    pull_policy="if-not-present"
    volumes = ["/certs/client", "/cache"]    
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

Answer (score 4):

The `pull_policy` only applies to images that the runner itself pulls. I.E. images you set in `image:` keys (or `services[]:name`).

If you use `docker` *inside* a job (e.g. where you use `docker-compose up -d`) when using the docker executor, then you cannot take advantage of cached layers and must pull the images from the registry first or build from scratch.

The reason for this is that docker-in-docker GitLab jobs use the `docker:dind` service as its docker daemon. This service comes up with a fresh state every time and therefore will not take advantage of cached images, even if the runner itself has the image cached.

You can, however, pull an image from your registry and use its as caches for your build using the `--cache-from` argument to `docker build`.

```yaml
script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
    - docker build --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
```

You still have to pull the image each time, of course, but this may be faster than building, especially if your image installs many dependencies or compiles large modules or something like that.

See the [docker-in-docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-workflow-with-docker-executor) section in the docs for more info.